# Why isn't my custom widget outputting any content?

Tags: widgets

I've been following numerous tutorials and codex pages in order to make my own widget in WP 4.0. It seems as though I'm very near; I can output *something* from the widget, just not any of the fields.

In banner.widget.php I have the following:

```
class bannerWidget extends WP_Widget {


        public $id_base          =  'banner_widget';
        public $name             =  'Banner Widget';
        public $widget_options   =  array(
                'classname'     =>  'RandomPostWidget',
                'description'   =>  'Displays a random post with thumbnail'
                );
        public $control_options  =  array();


        function bannerWidget() {
            parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Banner Widget', 'banner_widget') );
        }


        function form($instance) {
            // Check values
            if( $instance) {
                $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
                $text = esc_attr($instance['text']);
                $textarea = esc_textarea($instance['textarea']);
            } else {
                $title = '';
                $text = '';
                $textarea = '';
            }
            ?>

            <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Widget Title', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>"><?php _e('Text:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>"><?php _e('Textarea:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
            <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('textarea'); ?>"><?php echo $textarea; ?></textarea>
            </p>
            <?php
        }


        function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
            $instance = $old_instance;
            // Fields
            $instance['title']     =  strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
            $instance['text']      =  strip_tags($new_instance['text']);
            $instance['textarea']  =  strip_tags($new_instance['textarea']);
            return $instance;
        }


        public function widget($args, $instance){
            extract( $args );
            // these are the widget options
            $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
            $text = $instance['text'];
            $textarea = $instance['textarea'];
            echo $before_widget;
            // Display the widget
            echo '<div class="widget-text wp_widget_plugin_box">';
            // Check if title is set
            if ( $title ) {
                echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
            }
            // Check if text is set
            if( $text ) {
                echo '<p class="wp_widget_plugin_text">'.$text.'</p>';
            }
            // Check if textarea is set
            if( $textarea ) {
                echo '<p class="wp_widget_plugin_textarea">'.$textarea.'</p>';
            }

            echo '</div>';
            echo $after_widget;
        }

}

add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("bannerWidget");')
```

In functions.php:

```
function make_sidebar_area() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Test Sidebar Area',
        'id' => 'test_sidebar_1',
        'description' => 'Test sidebar description here',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'make_sidebar_area' );
```

And finally in index.php I have:

```
the_widget('bannerWidget');
```

This outputs the following, but none of the filled-in widget fields are showing:

```
<div class="widget widget_bannerwidget">
    <div class="widget-text wp_widget_plugin_box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Could somebody please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) denies those `$instance` variables being set, which they normally are when you stick it in a Sidebar in the back end.

Try something like this:

```
the_widget('bannerWidget', array(
    'title' => 'WordPress rocks!',
    'text' => 'Hello World.',
    'textarea' => 'Some content for the textarea'
) );
```

`the_widget` is for hard-coded widgets. To use the one placed in your custom sidebar, replace `the_widget()` with this:

```
echo '<ul class="sidebar">';
dynamic_sidebar( 'test_sidebar_1' );
echo '</ul>';
```

[`dynamic_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) is for displaying all widgets inside of the specified sidebar (passing the sidebar ID), where `the_widget` is for only rendering a specific widget, usually only used for something that has no options that need to be edited.

Comment: Well that certainly outputs something, but I need to have the widget configurable from the admin section. I guess I should be using something other than `the_widget()` - any advice on that? _Edit:_ Aha - I posted this comment before you edited. Thanks.

Comment: Normally you should create a sidebar and put it there.

Comment: Yes @verism, I made the answer more complete after reading it over. :)